# Mobile Site Redirector

Tags: php, html

Alright so i'm trying to develop a php script that will detect a device and redirect the user to a site depending on which device they have. I am running into trouble getting it to work fully. i would like it so that the user can have the option to visit the classic site or mobile site by clicking a hyperlink that sets the variable called "sitestyle" and this script checks for that variable using $_GET['sitestyle']; if variable=0 then send to desktop site. if variable=1 then send to mobile site and set session accordingly.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ((isset($_GET['sitestyle']) && ($_GET['sitestyle']=0)) {
$_SESSION['sitestyle']=0;
}
else ((isset($_GET['sitestyle']) && ($_GET['sitestyle']=1)) {
$_SESSION['sitestyle']=1;
}
//Separate Statements
if ((isset($_SESSION['sitestyle']) && ($_SESSION['sitestyle']=1)) {
header('Location: http://mobi.site.com/');
}
else if ((isset($_SESSION['sitestyle']) && ($_SESSION['sitestyle']=0)) {
exit();
}
else {

$tablet_browser = 0;
$mobile_browser = 0;

if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i',     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
$tablet_browser++;
}

if         (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i    ', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0)     or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0) {
$mobile_browser++;
//Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
$stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
    if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
  $tablet_browser++;
    }
}

if ($tablet_browser > 0) {
   // do something for tablet devices
   $_SESSION['sitestyle']=1;
  // print 'is tablet';
}
else if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
   // do something for mobile devices
     //  print 'is mobile';
   $_SESSION['sitestyle']=1;
    }
else {
   // do something for everything else
   //print 'is desktop';
   $_SESSION['sitestyle']=0;
    exit();
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: does this code work? does it give errors? What problems do you have? Have you considered server url rewriting instead? Also, be careful: users might get annoyed if you redirect them without their consent. I personally hate when this happens. My device is perfectly able to manage desktop sites even if it's a cellphone.

Comment: This is the error i keep getting:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home4/username/public_html/site.com/inc/mobileattach.php on line 4
I've checked everything and it still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You have the code as

```
$_GET['sitestyle']=0
```

which should be

```
$_GET['sitestyle'] == 0
```

and also

```
$_GET['sitestyle']=1
```

should be

```
$_GET['sitestyle'] == 1
```

Below is the correct syntax

```
if ( isset($_GET['sitestyle']) && $_GET['sitestyle']==0 ) {
    $_SESSION['sitestyle']=0;
}
elseif ( isset($_GET['sitestyle']) &&  $_GET['sitestyle']==1) {
    $_SESSION['sitestyle']=1;
}
```

Comment: He also did this with the `$_SESSION` on the next two `if()` statements

Answer (score 0):

You have one opening bracket too much on line 4!

```
if ((isset($_GET['sitestyle']) && ($_GET['sitestyle']=0)) {
---^
    $_SESSION['sitestyle']=0;
}
```

Remove the bracket and the error will be gone.

Please note this error happens multiple times in your page. Please check the brackets in your if-elseif-else statements.

Also note that the comparison operator is `==` and `===`. You're using the assignment operator, which is not what you want in this case.

Comment: I fixed all that but i still get the same error. Here is a snippet of the beginning lines:
`code` if (isset($_GET['sitestyle']) && ($_GET['sitestyle']== 0) {
        $_SESSION['sitestyle']=0;
    }
    else if (isset($_GET['sitestyle']) && ($_GET['sitestyle']== 1) {
        $_SESSION['sitestyle']=1;
    }

Comment: You did not follow my advice correctly. You removed 2 braces: the first one (which i told you to) and the last one (which you didn't have to, because that one was ok). So please fix as i told you. Then you'll be ok @MatthewMyers